# Need the small activity indicator in the status bar, similiar to WhatsApp

Tags: ios

I need the small activity indicator which is shown in the status bar (Network progress). I would add this one to a view.

Its like the one in WhatsApp, theyre using it for sending messages, and you see it in the small bubble.

How can I extract that?

Comment: I need this one:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-05-25/BFqrhctbemAmlyDDlhAFynetcqCdxaFAspIalasnGyCeFgAbBcgDjptsffuA/Screen_shot_2011-05-26_at_3.08.17_AM.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFZAE65UYRT34AOQ&Expires=1333921233&Signature=n%2BxaOfIxFK9eWX3SU9ZqiXVD6OE%3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is UIActivityIndicatorView, as mentioned already. The activity indicator has a property for its indicator style. This can be set to large white, small white, or gray.

Comment: Sorry, they're actually to big. Do you know WhatsApp? They have a smaller one, like the "network indicator" with just 8 "leafs".
How do I add this one?

Comment: If it's not one of the three (large white, small white, gray), then it's custom.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` property of `UIApplication`

From the Documentation:

> Specify `YES` if the application should show network activity and `NO` if it should not. The default value is `NO`. A spinning indicator in the status bar shows network activity. The application may explicitly hide or show this indicator.